# Prolog - sort results but return one by one

Tags: sorting, prolog

How to sort results in prolog by the last element in list, but still return them one by one, when pressing `;`, not just a list with all of them.

I have a predicate `route_with_total_dist/3` that returns lists with intermediary routes between point A and point B plus the train and direction. The total distance is the last element. For example:

```
?- route_with_total_dist(alexanderplatz, prinzenstrasse, R).
R = [[[alexanderplatz, u2, wittenbergplatz, ruhleben], [wittenbergplatz, u1, prinzenstrasse, 'warschauer strasse']], 11400] ;
R = [[[alexanderplatz, u2, wittenbergplatz, ruhleben], [wittenbergplatz, u3, nollendorfplatz, nollendorfplatz], [nollendorfplatz, u1, prinzenstrasse, 'warschauer strasse']], 11400] ;
R = [[[alexanderplatz, u2, nollendorfplatz, ruhleben], [nollendorfplatz, u1, prinzenstrasse, 'warschauer strasse']], 9800] ;
R = [[[alexanderplatz, u2, nollendorfplatz, ruhleben], [nollendorfplatz, u3, wittenbergplatz, 'krumme lanke'], [wittenbergplatz, u1, prinzenstrasse, 'warschauer strasse']], 11400] ;
R = [[[alexanderplatz, u2, gleisdreieck, ruhleben], [gleisdreieck, u1, prinzenstrasse, 'warschauer strasse']], 6900] ;
R = [[[alexanderplatz, u2, stadtmitte, ruhleben], [stadtmitte, u6, 'hallesches tor', 'alt-mariendorf'], ['hallesches tor', u1, prinzenstrasse, 'warschauer strasse']], 5000] ;
R = [[[alexanderplatz, u8, 'kottbusser tor', hermannstrasse], ['kottbusser tor', u1, prinzenstrasse, uhlandstrasse]], 3900] ;
false.
```

Now I would like to sort these results by the last element which is the total distance (shortest distance first), but still leave the option of being returned one by one. I know that I can do `findall/3` or `bagof/3` and then `sort/2`, but this will leave me with a huge list that will be just printed all at once.

In the example above (coincidentally) the results are printed in the exact opposite order that I want it. Expected would be:

```
R = [[[alexanderplatz, u8, 'kottbusser tor', hermannstrasse], ['kottbusser tor', u1, prinzenstrasse, uhlandstrasse]], 3900] ;
[[[alexanderplatz, u2, stadtmitte, ruhleben], [stadtmitte, u6, 'hallesches tor', 'alt-mariendorf'], ['hallesches tor', u1, prinzenstrasse, 'warschauer strasse']], 5000] ;
R = [[[alexanderplatz, u2, gleisdreieck, ruhleben], [gleisdreieck, u1, prinzenstrasse, 'warschauer strasse']], 6900] ;
...
...
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "one by one", you mean with backtracking, you can use [`member/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=member/2).

```
routes_one_by_one(A, B, R) :- route_with_total_dist(A, B, List), member(R, List).
```